# Google Sheets - Envio de E-Mail

Tags: javascript, google, envio-de-email, planilha

Tenho o seguinte código que faz o envio de e-mails através de uma planilha Google.

```
  function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var startRow = 2;


  var planMensagens = sheet.getSheetByName("mensagensEmail");
  var mensagemRef = planMensagens.getRange(2,3);
  var mensagem = mensagemRef.getValue();
  var tituloRef = planMensagens.getRange(2, 2);
  var titulo = tituloRef.getValue();



  //buscar valores para a linha no intervalo
  var data = sheet.getRange("base!A2:D4").getValues();

  for(i in data){
    var validaEnvio = "N";
    var row = data [i];
    var emailAddress = row [2]; //email
    var jaEnviouRef = row [3]; //coluna de referencia para envio

    if(jaEnviouRef == "" && emailAddress != "") {     

      //função para enviar os emails
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, titulo, mensagem);
      //PESQUINAR COMO ATUALIZAR O CAMPO PARA NÃO ENVIAR O MESMO EMAIL
     }
  }
}
```

Problema:

Quando eu envio o e-mail eu tenho que atualizar uma celula com o caracter "S", para que quando ele passar no

```
if(jaEnviouRef == "" && emailAddress !="")
```

Ele não executar o código.

Não estou conseguindo setar o valor.

Answer (score 0):

codigo para atualizar uma celula.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mensagensEmail").getRange("celula").setValue("S");
```

Link de referencia com exemplo:

[SetValue app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Ola @FilipeTD,

O problema é que dessa forma eu não consigo automatizar a ação.

Tentei algo assim, mas sem sucesso.

sheet.getRange(row[3]).setValue("S");

Comment: Sua pergunta está duplicada. Dê uma olhada nesse tópico.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235391/script-para-abertura-de-chamados-pelo-google-forms/239701#239701